# How to use localStorage effectively in JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I  used the HTML5 localStorage to keep the drop down box from changing when we refresh the page the code is something like this.

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#outerPage', function () {
    var local = localStorage.selectVal;
    if (local) {
        var selected = $('body').find('.ui-select-custom');
        //Select the value stored
        $(selected).val(local);
        if (local == 0) {
            $('span.ui-select-custom').html('Venta');
        } else $('span.ui-select-custom').html('Alquiler');
    }
    $(".ui-select-custom").bind("change", function (event, ui) {
        var currentVal = $(this).val();
        localStorage.setItem('selectVal', currentVal);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="ui-select-custom" data-mini="true">
    <option name="im_va" id="im_va" value="0">Venta</option>
    <option name="im_va" id="im_va" value="1">Alquiler</option>
</select>
```

It is working fine . but the problem is suppose if I open another window in the same browser there also it keeps the same value . It suppose to be in the default value.

Can some one please explain this

Thanks & regards

Comment: uhm... that's how local storage works? Opening in a new tab keeps the same session, that includes local storage. Open it in another browser instead.

Comment: Oh! I did not knew that I though I am writing wrong code . I didn't knew it will work like that  Then I may have to use the php $_Session[] ?? @KevinB

Comment: the php session will also be shared since both will use the same cookies

Comment: So what do you suggest is there any other way I could do this ?

Comment: change the word "localStorage" into "sessionStorage" to keep the refresh perisistence within one tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here seems to be that you're using local storage where session storage is the appropriate solution.

Local storage and session storage operate in two entirely different scopes, essentially meaning local storage is kept permanently for that domain while session storage is kept temporarily for that session.

Session storage is defined by browser windows or tabs in your case, so you will find swapping from local storage toward session storage should solve your problem and allow for two separate storage streams between your tabs.

This article helped me in the past fully understand this concept: [-link-](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-20/localstorage-and-sessionstorage)